# How do I make .ebextensions as root level in a war file while building war using mvn build commands?

Tags: maven, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Right now I first build the war file, then unzip it, then move .ebextensions into the unzipped directory and build war file again using the following command

```
jar -cvf fileName.war *
```

But I would like to do include .ebextensions to the root of war file using maven command. How to do that?

Comment: Simply put that file into `src/main/resources` directory. It will be packaged during the creation of the war file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer by myself. You have to have it under webapp directory

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzdCV.png

and then do `mvn clean install` as usual. After building the war, move it to another place and unzip it. You will see .ebextensions at the root of the war.